# Cabal library cannot import exposed modules

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have my foo.cabal file looking like this:

```
library
  exposed-modules:
      Foo.Bar,
      Foo.Something
  hs-source-dirs:      lib
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable foobar
  main-is:             Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Utils,  -- Local module in ./src
      Foo.Bar

  hs-source-dirs:      src
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

According to the sample code here: 
https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#example-a-package-containing-a-library-and-executable-programs

And I get the following error:

```
$ cabal build
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring foobar-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'foobar' for foobar-0.1.0.0..
cabal: can't find source for Foo/Bar in src, dist/build/foobar/autogen,
dist/build/global-autogen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line `build-depends:       foo` to your executable stanza to indicate the executable depends on the library you're defining.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the library to the dependencies of the executable. Here's the hpack version of your cabal file, I can never remember the cabal syntax:

```
name: foo
version: 0.1.0
dependencies:
  - base

source-dirs: lib

# no need for exponsed-modules, hpack does that for you

executable:
  main: Main.hs
  source-dirs: src
  dependencies:
    - base
    - foo
```

Or just use `stack new`, and you get a working project.

Comment: No way around stack huh? Seems like such a simple thing though for cabal, I wonder if I can get some more mileage out of it before I make the switch

Comment: Sorry, I actually switched to hpack and I still can't get the desired behavior. I need to both expose some library and add the exposes modules as dependencies to an executable. This solution doesn't declare the library part.